# My negative lookahead is not working - why?

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a text scattered with various strings, dates, tab characters and language codes. I want to extract the strings that follow a date+tab combination, and which are followed by a language code like '[en]', a tab character, and after which we don't have the string "BAD THINGS" (e.g. *"2020-01-12\tSTRING WE NEED[en]\tGOOD THINGS"*, as opposed to *"2020-01-12\tSTRING WE DON'T NEED[en]\tBAD THINGS"*).

Here is a short example text of what I'm working with:

*\n2021-01-12\tThis string is not needed [it]\tBad things\tBad things\n2021-01-12\tThis string is also not needed [en]\tBad things\tBad things\n2021-01-11\tString 1 that is needed! [it]\tString 1 that is needed! is repeated here\tNot interesting here\n2021-01-11\tString 2 that is needed [fr]\tString 2 that is needed is repeated here\tUnnecessary string\n2021-01-11\tString 3 that is needed... [ru]\tString 3 that is needed... is repeated here\tAnother part we're not interested in*

I made this regex to capture all strings between a date and a language code:

```
(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\\t)(.*?)(\[\w{2}\]\\t)
```

This works fine (see [here](https://regex101.com/r/bPVOrL/1)). However, when I add a negative lookahead to exclude those followed by "Bad things", all my regex goes south:

```
(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\\t)(.*?)(\[\w{2}\]\\t)(?!Bad things)
```

You can see the result [here](https://regex101.com/r/zOXoZU/1). I understand my lookahead somehow makes the regex greedy, but I have no idea how to avoid this, adding a ? after it doesn't work. Can you help me out here?

Comment: Please show the [mcve] in the question, rather than linking off site. One of the reasons is that the off-site resource may go away with time, leaving the SO question incomplete.

Comment: I updated the question. BTW the offsite links don't contain any extra information, I've only included them for convenience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this will cover all the cases but this seems to work:

```
(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\\t)([^][]*)(\[\w{2}\]\\t)(?!Bad things)
```

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/JYRz8h/1).

Explanation:

```
(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\\t)   date and tab
([^][]*)                 collect only things that do not contain chars `[` and `]`   
(\[\w{2}\]\\t)           follow up [<tag>]
(?!Bad things)           Negative Lookahead
```

Comment: (Small note) You don't have to make the negated character class non greedy using the `?` as the brackets can not cross matching `[it]` for example. `(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\\t)([^][]*)(\[\w{2}]\\t)(?!Bad things)` see https://regex101.com/r/hLyjSk/1

Comment: Thanks @Thefourthbird updated the answer based on your suggestion!